# How do I debug Tangled 0 code blocks?

Tags: org-babel, debugging, tangle

This is a history of an unsuccessful attempt to fix tangling in my Emacs configuration. In frustration, I have removed the org-mode config and left the file that was a result of previous successful tangling.

https://github.com/bigos/prelude/commit/a1c5ae478d3b0315bb468a869ccb6d488dda04bf

This is a complete mystery to me. Few days ago org-babel-tangle has stopped working. Using git to revert to my configuration that used to tangle correctly did not help. I would get just

> Tangled 0 code blocks from organised.org

and nothing else.

Accidentally I have found that `M-x org-reload` gives me an error that makes no sense to me.

```
The following features were found in load-path, please check if that’s
correct: (ob-restclient obarray) Some error occurred while reloading
Org feature (organised) Please check *Messages*! Org mode version
9.5.4 (release_9.5.4 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/)
```

Starting with `emacs -q` and trying to tangle gives:

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Tangled 0 code blocks from organised.org You can run the command
‘org-babel-tangle’ with C-c C-v t Tangled 0 code blocks from
organised.org
```

trying `M-x org-reload` gives:

```
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-comint...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-core...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-emacs-lisp...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-eval...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-exp...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-lob...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-ref...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-table...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/ob-tangle...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/obarray...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-compat...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-element...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-entities...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-faces...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-footnote...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-keys...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-list...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-macro...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-macs...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-pcomplete...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-src...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-table...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org-version.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/org...done
The following feature was found in load-path, please check if that’s correct:
(obarray)
Successfully reloaded Org
Org mode version 9.5.4 (release_9.5.4 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/)
You can run the command ‘org-reload’ with C-c C-x !
Successfully reloaded Org
Org mode version 9.5.4 (release_9.5.4 @ /usr/local/share/emacs/28.1.50/lisp/org/)
```

Comment: You should add  to your question a minimal example file that exhibits the problem. But it sounds to me as if your installation has been somehow corrupted: search for "mixed installation" and the `org` tag in this site and see if anything helps.

Comment: For the `org-reload` problems, I presume you have tried killing your emacs and starting it again? If not, try that.

Comment: To be honest even killall emacs did not help. I hope that one day I will recompile emacs and the problem will disappear. I use GNU Emacs 28.1.50.

Comment: In the org-reload errors, I posted above, it complains about oberror. that symbol is used in some prelude packages. I wonder if that is a problem. But strangely my org config seems to work despite removing the tangled file altogether. Strange

Comment: The config still works because it was saved in custom.el file. Maybe I need to review that as well?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about: there is nothing about "oberror". There is a complaint about "obarray" which is a very-low level data structure in elisp, basically a symbol table (search the Elisp manual for more details). I don't know what the **feature** `(obarray)' is that it's complaining about and I have no idea what your "org config" is and why it has anything to do with the tangled file or why it is saved in the custom file. If you expect help, you will have to provide much more information, but it is very hard to debug a complicated problem with lots of twisty passages ...

Comment: ... remotely. I suspect that you will have to do most, if not all of the heavy lifting. And in any case, the best place to add more information is in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @NickD thank you for your suggestions. This problem made me think about giving up on using org-mode for the configuration. With yafolding-mode and having the code from previous successful tangling I will think of different approach. This is my config  https://github.com/bigos/prelude